# AdonisJS catch database insert errors with api-only while using ORM

Tags: orm, try-catch, adonis.js

Is there a way to catch database insert errors i.e. duplicate entry when using the Adonis ORM in api-only mode.

In the example below, if the username is a duplicate, it just sends a 500 internal server error and dumps a full html page of the error to the client.

Even if I don't know what the error is, I would at least like to be able to catch the error and send a more usable json object like

`{error: "Unable to insert user"}`

Here is some example code

```
const User = use('App/Models/User')

class UserController {
    async register({ request }) {
        const { username, email, password, first_name, last_name } = request.all()
        const user = new User()
        user.fill({
            username,
            email,
            password,
            first_name,
            last_name
        })
        await user.save()
        return user
    }
}
```

**Partly Solved:**
I have partly solved this issue with the following code, but I feel as though there must be a better / built in way to achieve this.

```
const User = use('App/Models/User')

class UserController {
    async saveData(object, errorMessage){
        try{
            await object.save()
            return object
        }
        catch(err) {
            return {error:`${errorMessage}`}
        }
    }
    async register({ request, response }) {
        const { username, email, password, first_name, last_name } = request.all()
        const user = new User()
        user.fill({
            username,
            email,
            password,
            first_name,
            last_name
        })
        return this.saveData(user, "Unable to save user")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try & catch is what you're looking for. You can also use [global exceptions](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/exceptions).

Regarding your duplicate error, you should also use the [AdonisJs Validator](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/validator) to make sure you won't get this errors.

So before you save your model, check that the given user is unique for example.

So you would have something like this

```
async register({ request, response }) {
    const { username, email, password, first_name, last_name } = request.all()

    const rules = {
      username: 'required|unqiue:username'
    };

    const validation = await validate(request.all(), rules);

    if (validation.fails()) {
      response.status(500).send(validation.messages());
    }

    const user = new User()
    user.fill({
        username,
        email,
        password,
        first_name,
        last_name
    })

    await user.save();

    return user;

}
```